# How to replace componentDidMount with getderivedstatefromprops?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use getderivedstatefromprops to update the state of selectedPlan when it receives a different number from the prop defaultPlan.

I have tried to convert componentDidMount to getderivedstatefromprops, but getderivedstatefromprops does not seem to be getting called in my component?

```
state = {
    selectedPlan: 0,
};

static getderivedstatefromprops(props, state){
  if (props.defaultPlan !== state.selectedPlan) {
    return{
      selectedPlan: props.defaultPlan
    };
  }
  return null;
}

componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.plans.length > this.props.defaultPlan) {
    this.setState({ selectedPlan: this.props.defaultPlan });
  }
}
```

I am using this in a PureComponent, and I'm not sure if thats the reason why it is not working?

Comment: Probably just an in issue with case-sensitivity, it looks like you need to define getderivedstatefromprops in camel-case. See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-hooks-ihxfx

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Awesome, that fixed the issue!

Comment: You're welcome Winsome and congrats on the internship :)